# How to debug a Goland project using cgo opencv?

Tags: opencv, debugging, goland

I actualy treat this project as any other pure go project and expect it to be debugged by simply clicking dthe "Debug" button.

But I get this error:

```
/tmp/go-build1999814797/b331/_x001.o：In function ‘cvContourPerimeter’：
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h:364：undefined reference to ‘cvArcLength’
...
```

When I can click the "Run" button and it runs correctly. What is the difference between run and debug? Am I missing something important?

I tried to google this and ask ChatGPT about how to solve this problem but it didnt go well.

Comment: Sounds like some dynamic debug libraries cannot be found. Please share versions of OS, IDE and opencv, so others can better try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: OS：ubuntu 18.04（Docker container runs on Ubuntu 22.04）                                                  IDE:  Goland 2022.2.5                                                                                                            OpenCV: 2.4.13.6

Comment: Try to disable CGO to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem!
I edit the C header file imgproc_c.h by commenting the two CV_INLINE functions then the Debug works. But what is strange is that I rollback what I have done before the debug is still working. Maybe is something about inline compiling?